# Error installing WebLogic server using Console mode in windows 8.1

Tags: oracle, weblogic

Hi i have been trying to install the server weblogic of oracle on windows 8.1 but I obtain the follow when I run the `configure.cmd` file:

> **ERROR**: You must set MW_HOME and it must point to a directory where an
>   installation of WebLogic exists. Ensure you point this variable to the
>   extract location of the zip distribution.

How do I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a readme file linked from the product download page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html although your experience would suggest that defining MW_HOME isn't optional! ...

```
1. Extract the contents of the zip to a directory (eg: /home/myhome/mywls)
   This will create a base directory named wls12130 under /home/myhome/mywls
   MW_HOME will be the entire directory including the base directory. 
   (eg: MW_HOME will be /home/myhome/mywls/wls12130).

2. Setup JAVA_HOME and optionally, MW_HOME variables in the current shell as required
   for the target platform.

  Windows
    > set JAVA_HOME=C:\home\myhome\myjavahome
    > set MW_HOME=C:\home\myhome\mywls\wls12130

3. Run the installation configuration script in the MW_HOME directory.

  This step is required to be run only once. If you move the installation to 
  another location/machine, you need to rerun this step.

  Windows
    > configure.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are not set properly.

1.- Create product directory

mkdir E:\weblogic\wls  << I'm sure you did it and Weblogic binaries are already installed.

2.- set environment variables properly

set JAVA_HOME=_path_to_\jdk1.7.0

set MW_HOME=E:\weblogic\wls

(change above settings according to your installation)

3.- Run configure.cmd